# Opening "live copies" of files on shared drives from an intranet

Tags: html, intranet

I'm working on a company intranet, the idea is to consolidate important company schedules (which are excel based) in one place.

It's simple, & im using: "file:///Z:\Spreadsheet.xlsx" as an href to open an excel spreadsheet.. this works after some browser security settings modifications.

The problem is that since HTTP is a transfer protocol, the browser downloads the file, then opens the copy that was downloaded.

I'm trying to have the link directly open the original excel file copy. Any ideas for this approach? Since it is an intranet, I have the freedom to deploy software that can help me accomplish this.

Thanks.

Comment: One would have to use a Network-Aware Filesystem. SMB (Windows File Shares and Samba) is probably the most common. There is also NFS. Once the remote FS/drive is “connected” (ie. mapped/mounted network drive) they operate similarly to a local FS - for some value of similarly. (The specific restrictions may or may not be suitable for the specific problem at hand, depending on required access semantics; regardless, there is no distinct “local copy” and file changes are automatically propagated.)

Comment: My problem isn't opening the file, I'm able to do that and the network drive is mapped to all of our computers. My issue is opening the original copy of the file, since browsers want to "download" the file from the local server and then open that copy instead of the original version stored on the network drive.

Comment: You are not using SMB or NFS. See above. The file:// protocol is being treated as a “download” and has nothing to do with mapped/mounted network drives. A mapped drive can be accessed as a “local” volume: M:\foo.txt (system drivers transparently handle the FS access). In Windows, a UNC path can also be used directly: \\\\server\share\foo.txt (uses SMB protocol).

Comment: I'm sorry I thought you misunderstood. "Network File System (NFS) is a network file system protocol originally developed by Sun Microsystems in 1984,allowing a user on a client computer to access files over a network in a manner similar to how local storage is accessed." NFS being a protocol tells me that it interfaces between html and our server's current mapped network drive filesystem, right? Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just saw your edit. If I link using SMB, I should be able to open files in mydesired scenario?

Comment: To map a network drive: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v%3dws.11) (and probably something in PowerShell). These all relate to SMB, which has been supported in Windows for about 3 decades.. Windows requires a third-party driver to map NFS.

Comment: It should be possible to access a remote SMB share just with the UNC (it’s handled internally in Windows) instead of needing to map first. Of course, sometimes programs make incorrect assumptions about paths that a ‘mapped drive’ can avoid.

Comment: I've tried making my href as follows, using UNC style paths: href="\\SEFS1\Energy\Technical%20Library\Engineering%20Interface.xlsx". This didn't work, instead it tries to download the file & I've found that Google Chrome will add file: to the URL path. Note that I have the intranet hosted on my own web-server due to company security policies, though I don't think it should matter? My thought is that the href should command excel to open, and open this file with it. After all, HTTP is a "transfer" protocol?

Comment: Launch Excel locally using the UNC path. Any downloads / copies have already broken the association.

Comment: If I browse to file://///sefs1/energy/Technical%20Library/ in my library, I can see the file I'm trying to open- if I click it I get a download. If I type ///sefs1/energy/Technical%20Library/Engineering%20Interface.xlsx into my browser bar, I get an IIS 404 not found. If I launch the file locally from file explorer using \\SEFS1\Energy\Technical Library\Engineering Interface.xlsx, I get the file to open- repeat the process in the browser and I am offered a download again.